# Android App Actions does not work with voice command

Tags: android, actions-on-google, app-actions

I am trying to implement app actions and slice (for fulfillment) in my android app. I am testing the feature with "App Actions Test Tool" and the slice loads up immediate when I hit "Run" in the tool but the Slice does not work with the Voice command.
Is the feature available to launch slice using voice command. I already have a draft posted on play store and using the same account for Android studio and the assistant.

Expected that the slice would launch with the voice command of the intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should work for most App Actions, however, you will need to test with the correct phrase. Some App Actions may also not work correctly via voice at this time, if so you can file a bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=617864).

To test this out:

1. Review the test phrases under each built-in intent in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/built-in-intents/).
2. Configure or check your invocation name in the Studio Test Tool plugin:
   [image]
3. Invoke the test phrase with your invocation name by speaking or by typing (typing can be easier for testing initially).
4. I recommend you try first with the [Fit Actions sample app](https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin) along with the START and STOP exercise App Actions as these should work reliably.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent the weekend trying to get the sample to work, only to see this...

From: https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/overview

Check the big grey box at the top of the page: "You can build and test App Actions, but user triggering from the Assistant is not available yet."

:(