# What is the proper syntax for testing app actions via voice using google assistant?

Tags: android, actions-on-google, app-actions

I am currently writing an Android app in Kotlin to test out the new built in app actions provided by Google. At the moment, looking at actions.intent.GET_ACCOUNT.

I already have Android Studio, my google assistant and my device all connected with the same developer account. I have also uploaded a draft onto the play store with the same package name. I am able to get the app action to run with the test tool but not able to invoke it via voice using Google Assistant.

I have also consulted this link for help but no luck [Android App Actions does not work with voice command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56139330/android-app-actions-does-not-work-with-voice-command/56143392#56143392)

What I am saying into Google Assistant is something along the lines of "Hey Google view my account with Big Money". However, all I get is an online search result. Is there something obvious that I am missing? Thanks!

My Manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.actions" android:resource="@xml/actions" />

    <activity
            android:name=".views.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="martymoneybank.com"
                    android:pathPattern="/account"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

My Action.xml:

```
<actions>
<action intentName="actions.intent.GET_ACCOUNT" >

    <fulfillment urlTemplate="http://martymoneybank.com/account{?accountType}">
        <parameter-mapping
                intentParameter="account.name"
                urlParameter="accountType" />
    </fulfillment>
</action>
```

Test Tool:

[Test Tool View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDJs6.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the general troubleshooting steps for this kind of situation. If it works via the Studio Test Tool, but it doesn't work via voice, then there's two potential issues:

1. You are using the wrong (or an unsupported) phrase that Assistant cannot match to the App Action. To find example queries, go [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/built-in-intents/), find the Assistant intent and look at the example queries. Eg.
   [image]

   However, in your case, `GET_ACCOUNT` does not have any example queries so please file a bug for this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=617864&template=1257475).
2. It's a bug on the Assistant side. If you try the example queries and it still doesn't work (but it works fine via the Studio Test Tool), then please [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=617864&template=1257475).

---

That said, for `GET_ACCOUNT` could you try and see if these phases work (its also worth noting that you can use the keyboard to enter the phrases if Assistant is having any issues transcribing what you are saying, of course without the "hey google"):

> hey google, get savings account balance using *Big Money*

or

> hey google, check my savings account balance on *Big Money*

or

> hey google, ask *Big Money* to tell me my savings account balance

Comment: Hey Adam! I tried the phrases you provided and no luck. I will file the bug with the tracker. Thanks!

Comment: @MartyDang thanks for giving it a go, sorry it's not working as it should be. definitely file a bug in the tracker. you can also try testing say, START_EXERCISE which should definitely work with the example phrases.

Comment: Same issue for me. Will file an issue as voice commands for my intent `actions.intent.RECORD_HEALTH_OBSERVATION` are not working

Comment: @Benjamin yes please do file an issue. In the case of RECORD_HEALTH_OBSERVATION there are example queries in the docs so try those, but if they aren't working (but the test tool is working) then you should file an issue.

Comment: @Marty Do we have to upload the actions.xml to dev console to test this? Did you have to fill out a form to do this? We can test our actions with app actions test tool

Comment: @Gravity to test it you can just use the App Actions Test Tool Studio plugin. For testing it, you do not meed to fill out a form nor upload to the console. Although you will need a draft listing in Play Console to test it using the Test Tool (it doesn't need actions.xml in the draft). See here for more info: https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/get-started#preview